# Unconfirmed bitcoins 258: txn-mempool-conflict

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions, doublespend

I made a transaction a few days ago, but the fee was to low so it doesn't get confirmed. So I want to give the transaction a higher fee. But when I resend the transaction I get this error:

`258: txn-mempool-conflict`

I restarted my server.
I tried leaving the output the same but added an input.
I tried changing the output to an higher fee and left the input the same.
I tried the `abandontransaction` command but that returns `Transaction not eligible for abandonment`.
But the error is still there. How can I resend my transaction so it will get confirmed?

Comment: Are you using Bitcoin Core? Did you try using `-zapwallettxes` or `-abandontransaction`? Have you seen [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Comment: -zapwallettxes doesn't work because I run bitcoind in prune. And -abandontransaction returns the same error.

Comment: `abandontransaction` wouldn't work, because the offending transaction is also in your memory pool.